# Parallel foreach loop with async code doesn't complete correctly for unknown reason

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to rewrite a `foreach` loop to use `Parallel.ForEach` since every document I need to process can be handled as s separate entity there are no dependencies what so ever.

The code is fairly straight forward as below:

- Query the DB
- Read each document in the loop
- For each document do two web calls and add results to the document
- Add updated document to list
- BulkImport list to DB

Since the web API calls are the slowest part due to network delay, I wanted to process them in parallell to save time so I wrote this code

```
private async Task<List<String>> FetchDocumentsAndBuildList(string brand)
{
    using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(cosmosDBEndpointUrl), cosmosDBPrimaryKey))
    {
        List<string> formattedList = new List<string>();
        FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = -1,
            PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(brand)
        };

        var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(cosmosDBName, cosmosDBCollectionNameRawData), $"SELECT TOP 2 * from c where c.brand = '{brand}'", queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

        while(query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 };

            Parallel.ForEach(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>(), options, async singleDocument =>
            {
                JObject originalData = singleDocument.GetPropertyValue<JObject>("BasicData");

                if (originalData != null)
                {
                    var artNo = originalData.GetValue("artno");
                    if (artNo != null)
                    {
                        string strArtNo = artNo.ToString();
                        string productNumber = strArtNo.Substring(0, 7);
                        string colorNumber = strArtNo.Substring(7, 3);
                        string HmGoeUrl = $"https://xxx,xom/Online/{strArtNo}/en";
                        string sisApiUrl = $"https:/yyy.com/{productNumber}/{colorNumber}?&maxnumberofstores=10&brand=000&channel=02";
                        string HttpFetchMethod = "GET";

                        JObject detailedDataResponse = await DataFetcherAsync(HmGoeUrl, HttpFetchMethod);
                        JObject inventoryData = await DataFetcherAsync(sisApiUrl, HttpFetchMethod);

                        if (detailedDataResponse != null)
                        {
                            JObject productList = (JObject)detailedDataResponse["product"];

                            if (productList != null)
                            {
                                var selectedIndex = productList["articlesList"].Select((x, index) => new { code = x.Value<string>("code"), Node = x, Index = index })
                                .Single(x => x.code == strArtNo)
                                .Index;

                                detailedDataResponse = (JObject)productList["articlesList"][selectedIndex];
                            }
                        }

                        singleDocument.SetPropertyValue("DetailedData", detailedDataResponse);
                        singleDocument.SetPropertyValue("InventoryData", inventoryData);
                        singleDocument.SetPropertyValue("consumer", "NWS");
                    }
                }
                formattedList.Add(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(singleDocument));
            });


            //foreach (Document singleDocument in await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>())
            //{
            //    JObject originalData = singleDocument.GetPropertyValue<JObject>("BasicData");

            //    if(originalData != null)
            //    {
            //        var artNo = originalData.GetValue("artno");
            //        if(artNo != null)
            //        {
            //            string strArtNo = artNo.ToString();
            //            string productNumber = strArtNo.Substring(0, 7);
            //            string colorNumber = strArtNo.Substring(7, 3);
            //            string HmGoeUrl = $"https:/xxx.xom/Online/{strArtNo}/en";
            //            string sisApiUrl = $"https://yyy.xom&maxnumberofstores=10&brand=000&channel=02";
            //            string HttpFetchMethod = "GET";

            //            JObject detailedDataResponse = await DataFetcherAsync(HmGoeUrl, HttpFetchMethod);
            //            JObject inventoryData = await DataFetcherAsync(sisApiUrl, HttpFetchMethod);

            //            if(detailedDataResponse != null)
            //            {
            //                JObject productList = (JObject)detailedDataResponse["product"];

            //                if(productList != null)
            //                {
            //                    var selectedIndex = productList["articlesList"].Select((x, index) => new { code = x.Value<string>("code"), Node = x, Index = index })
            //                    .Single(x => x.code == strArtNo)
            //                    .Index;

            //                    detailedDataResponse = (JObject)productList["articlesList"][selectedIndex];
            //                }
            //            }

            //            singleDocument.SetPropertyValue("DetailedData", detailedDataResponse);
            //            singleDocument.SetPropertyValue("InventoryData", inventoryData);
            //            singleDocument.SetPropertyValue("consumer", "NWS");
            //        }
            //    }
            //    formattedList.Add(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(singleDocument));
            //}
        }
        return formattedList;
    }
}
```

If I add a breakpoint in the loop, I can see the correct values are assigned to each variable but for some reason the `formattedList` returned is always 0 entries and I cannot figure out why.

Commented out is the original `foreach` loop that works just fine but is slooooow

--- EDIT ---
THis is how I am calling this code from the parent method

```
   log.LogInformation($"Starting creation of DocumentList for BulkImport at: {DateTime.Now}");

   var documentsToImportInBatch = await FetchDocumentsAndBuildList(brand);

   log.LogInformation($"BulkExecutor DocumentList has: {documentsToImportInBatch.Count} entries, created at: {DateTime.Now}");
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing your `List<>` with a `ConcurrentBag<>`? As far as I know, Lists aren't designed to be used in concurrent code.

Comment: @RobinB You beat me at that ;)

Comment: It still fails, its like it returns the empty bag before the loops finish retrieving the data and adding it to the bag? I break after the bag.Add and I can see the count increase for every iteration of the loop, but the code doesn't stop it already returns the empty bag to the calling method

Comment: @StuartLC yes I am trying to change it to TPL steep learning curve though but seems powerful and good fit

Comment: Using the `Parallel` class for async work is a common mistake. It doesn't understand async delegates, meaning that it doesn't accept lambdas that return `Task`s. So when you feed it with an `async () =>` lambda, an `async void` is created. Async void's are a problem by themselves. They can't be awaited, and their exceptions can't be handled. Unfortunately there is no class analogous to `Parallel` for async work. We have nothing in between the `Task.WhenAll` which is very basic, and the super powerful TPL Dataflow library that does everything you can imagine but has learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't understand that each call to your lambda returning a `Task` needs to be awaited before the `ForEach` can be considered complete.

As a result, the continuation after the await isn't invoked before your function exits, and this is why `formattedList` has zero elements in it.

You can easily prove this with a code sample such as:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 100), async singleDocument => await Task.Delay(9999));
Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

`Done` will be printed almost immediately.

For I/O bound parallelism, you could instead use `Task.WhenAll` to parallelize your async webscraping calls

```
var myDocuments = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>();
var myScrapingTasks = myDocuments.Select(async singleDocument =>
{
       // ... all of your web scraping code here
       // return the amended (mutated) document
       return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(singleDocument);
});
var results = await Task.WhenAll(myScrapingTasks);
formattedList.AddRange(results);
```

w.r.t `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, if you find that you need to throttle the number of concurrent scraping calls, easiest would be to [group the incoming documents into manageable chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419063/314291) and processing the smaller chunks at a time - the `Select(x, i)` overload and `GroupBy` work wonders.